# How to expand the new Windows Terminal to support AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-terminal

Loving the new Terminal but often I need to SSH into an EC2 instance on AWS. Right now I open an Ubuntu tab and then SSH into EC2. I see in the dropdown Azure Cloud Shell. Is there a way to directly SSH into AWS in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case others search for this same issue. First I made sure OpenSSH was installed, configured, and working.

Then inside my .ssh directory, I added my EC2 server to the list in the config file.

Finally I opened the settings for Terminal and added an entry for it:

```
    {
        "name": "DevBox",
        "commandline": "ssh my-ec2-instance",
        "icon": "C:/Users/macaw/OneDrive/Pictures/aws.png"
    }
```